# How do I see all the methods/ properties in Object Class

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, irb

I have started learning Rails 3.0 and decided to spend sometime learning Pure Ruby 1.9 and wonder if there is a way to View the Object Class since it is always available. Like is there a command that you can type in IRB for example that will display all the methods in Object Class like to_a, to_s, etc.. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`#methods` is the method you want. It simply returns an array of symbols, which are all the names of the methods that object responds to.

```
Object.new.methods
```

Or more readable in irb:

```
puts Object.new.methods.sort.to_yaml
```

Or for the class methods:

```
Object.methods
```

---

One caveat though, some objects allow methods that won't be listed here. Anything implemented with a hook into `#method_missing` won't show up.  This includes a lot of `ActiveRecord` methods as well as other rails objects.

But so long as nothing tricky is going on, this is the list you seem to want.

Comment: Niggle: ``methods`` returns an array of symbols, not strings.

Comment: In ruby 1.8.7 you get strings, which is sadly what I'm most familiar with.

Comment: yea thanx very helpful, Thought no one will understand my question, thanks

Comment: Ruby is a very dynamic language, and with that comes a ton of _reflection_ (inspection of its own implemention). This is one of the many many ways ruby can get you info on what your objects are composed of.

Answer (score 3):

To see an object's methods, you can do `your_object.methods`. For a class, this will be its class methods. To see a class's instance methods, you can do `your_class.instance_methods`. So to list all the class methods of Object, you'd do `Object.methods`, and to see all the instance methods of Object, you'd do `Object.instance_methods`.

Further tip: If you want to see only the methods that a given class implements (not methods inherited from its ancestors), you can pass `false` as the argument to either of the methods I mentioned earlier. So, for example, `String.instance_methods(false)` will return a list of instance methods that String implements, but will not return general Object methods like `dup` and `is_a?`.

However, if you're trying to learn, looking at the docs for a given class or class extension (such as Rails' additions to String or Date) would probably be better.